# get attribute values from child node using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to get the a child's node attributes based on the name of the parent node which is selected from a Listbox.

The problem is within the Xpath string "//Class[@Name='"+curItem+"']/Entity". When I replace the variable with the name of the attribute(ECMInstruction) it displays correctly but with the variable it doesn't.

Here is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Class Name="ECMInstruction" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="DocumentInformation" />
  </Class>
  <Class Name="dfgfggfdg" Style="Top">
    <Entity Id="1" Name="dfgfgfdgd" />
  </Class>
```

---

```
private void dcLisT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //EntityList.Items.Clear();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load("sample.xml");
    String curItem = dcList.SelectedItem.ToString();
    XmlNodeList nodes = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Class[@Name='"+curItem+"']/Entity");

    foreach(XmlNode x in nodes){
        String EntityID=(x.Attributes["Id"].Value);
        String EntityName = (x.Attributes["Name"].Value);
        EntityList.Items.Add("Entity ID #"+EntityID+" "+EntityName);
    }          

}
```

Comment: Then the variable most likely doesn't contain exactly what you think/expect it does.  Have you checked by comparing `curItem` with `"ECMInstruction"` right before using it in that string?

Comment: Yes of course i did that .the variable contais that name

Comment: Well there _has_ to be a difference between those values, otherwise there wouldn't be a difference in the programs behaviour.  How have you checked?  By comparing the values with code or just by looking at a printed representation of the value(s)?